# Can't get query parameter from HttpRequestData

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm upgrading my code from .NET 3.0 to .NET 5.0, this changes the sintaxis quite a bit.
In my previous code, which is a http request build in AZURE FUNCTIONS .NET 5.0 isolate, builds an GET api that takes parameters.

This is my previous code from .NET 3.0

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs; 
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;


public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
  ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    byte[] RSA_Key_to_Correct = new byte[0x80];
    string array_var = req.Query["array_var"];
    string i = req.Query["i"];
    string incrementing_value = req.Query["incrementing_value"];
}
```

I just cant find a way to use **req** to grab a parameter from the api call like it was done on .NET 3.0 `string i = req.Query["i"];`

In .NET 5.0 im using

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
```

Any hint?

Comment: Are you looking for [Request.QueryString("fullname")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8)? (can't get't the square brackets right in the link). Intellisense reveals all the members. Use it!

Comment: It wont work since im using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http; for .NET 5.0, this only works for .NET -4.8.
For .NET 5.0 i suppose to be using HttpRequestData

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation for that class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httprequestdata?view=azure-dotnet)? Did that contain any information about the URL or the parameters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67969169/1672994 will answer your query. You should be using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers package in .net 5 to get and parse query parameters.

Comment: Don't you just love it when MS removes functionality for no reason!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Azure function .NET 5.0, we use the `HttpRequestData` in Http Trigger. The class does not contain `Query` parameter. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httprequestdata?view=azure-dotnet)
[image]

So if you want to get query string, you can use the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers` to implement it as @user1672994 said.

For example

```
var queryDictionary = 
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(req.Url.Query);
var result = queryDictionary["<key name>"];
```

Comment: I think installing the additional ASP.NET Core package is redundant. One can simply use the following: `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(req.Url.Query);`, followed by `var result = queryDictionary["<key name>"]; `

Answer (score 27):

There is a system package that gives the same result. That is probably why it was removed. Just use:

```cs
var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(req.Url.Query);
var from = query["key"]
```

This gives the same result as req.Query["array_var"];

Enjoy

Answer (score 15):

You can just add the the query parameter name to the function parameter list as follows and access the value:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req, 
      FunctionContext executionContext, string parameter1)
    {
        var log = executionContext.GetLogger("TestParam");
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        log.LogInformation($"Parameter Value: {parameter1}");

    }
```

Comment: Your answer isn't about the isolated process functions. The `HttpRequest` isn't available there.

Comment: @Stephan yes I made a mistake by copying the same code as in question. Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the answer but still how I handled the query parameter is same and its applicate for isolated functions.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Azure Functions (isolated) with .NET 5.0 - you can get it out of `FunctionContext.BindingContext.BindingData` like this:

```cs
functionContext.BindingContext
               .BindingData["weatherForecastId"]
               .ToString();
```

```cs
[Function("WeatherForecastGet")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Get([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "weather/{weatherForecastId:required}")] HttpRequestData req,
                                        FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    string weatherForecastId = executionContext.BindingContext
                                               .BindingData["weatherForecastId"]
                                               .ToString();

    var result = this.doSomething(weatherForecastId);
    
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(result);

    return response;
}
```

---

As the question asked about the `HttpRequestData`. The `FunctionContext` is also available in it. So you can achieve the same results (with more steps) like this:

```cs
httpRequestData.FunctionContext
               .BindingContext
               .BindingData["weatherForecastId"]
               .ToString();
```

```cs
[Function("WeatherForecastGet")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Get([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "weather/{weatherForecastId:required}")] HttpRequestData req,
                                        FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    string weatherForecastId = req.FunctionContext
                                  .BindingContext
                                  .BindingData["weatherForecastId"]
                                  .ToString();

    // some logic
}
```

---

This also works with the parameter in both query and path. As you can see both parameters in the API path below is in the `BindingData`

```
/api/weather/12?range=today
```

[image: Debugger]

Answer (score -3):

This works for me. Nice and simple. There is a method to get the query params into a dictionary.

```
var qp = req.GetQueryParameterDictionary();

var foobar = req["foobar"];
```

Comment: This doens't seem to be available in Functions .NET 5 running in isolated mode.

Comment: The question was about isolated process.  You may want to consider deleting your answer.