# QueryParameter extract from URL in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, query-string

Url: `http://localhost:3000/Login/SignIn?timeout=5000&returnUrl=/Home.ashx?param1=555&param2=666`

Output:

```
{
    [0]: { timeout, 3000 },
    [1]: { param1, 555 },
    [2]: { param2, 666 }
}
```

Comment: that uri seems malformed; the `/`, `?`, `=`, `&` etc tokens in the `returnUrl` should have been url-encoded, surely? i.e. `...&returnUrl=%2FHome.ashx%3Fparam1%3D555%26param2%3D666` ? then the `timeout` is a simple decode, but you'd need to re-parse the value of `returnUrl` and extract those *inner* parameter values

Comment: It makes no sense to both use individually unique names for your values _and_ keep all values in isolated objects. This isn't a question, it's an implicit expectation to finish/correct a half-baked idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get query parameter from HttpRequestData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087731/cant-get-query-parameter-from-httprequestdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the `returnUrl` here is incorrectly encoded, and in the real code would be url-encoded; in that case, you need a second pass to parse the return-url parameters, but - something like:

```cs
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:3000/Login/SignIn?timeout=5000&returnUrl=%2FHome.ashx%3Fparam1%3D555%26param2%3D666");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
foreach (string key in query.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}={query[key]}");
}
// further-decode returnUrl values
uri = new Uri(uri, query["returnUrl"]);
query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
foreach (string key in query.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}={query[key]}");
}
```

which outputs:

```
timeout=5000
returnUrl=/Home.ashx?param1=555&param2=666
param1=555
param2=666
```